# What is the best way to archive git libraries on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I feel like I have a lot of libraries on my GitHub that clutter it up, and they would be great to remove or hide, but at the same time I don't want to delete them forever. What have other people done to sort of "archive" their libraries so they don't show up on GitHub but are retrieval later?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would store those libraries in an [artifact repository like Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), in order to declare and record their exact versions in a `pom.xml` file (which you can version in your GitHub repository)

In other word, you wouldn't store your libraries directly in source control, you would only store the *declaration* of said libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your repository with `git clone` and delete it from Github. The clone is an exact copy containing the entire history. Back it up however you would choose to back up any other data. Zip it, burn it to disc or store it in the cloud with your favourite backup service. You can include the wiki by enabling Git access and cloning it as well.

Comment: It would be nice if this could be automated in the cloud somewhere instead of having to keep a local copy and be responsible for it.